# "I just know that..." or "I just knew that.."

Tags: grammar

If I want to refer to the time about two minuites before now, which one should I use?

- I just *know* that...
- I just *knew* that...

or either one? [Click to view the N-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20just%20know%20that,%20I%20just%20knew%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,I%20just%20know%20that;,c0;.t1;,I%20just%20knew%20that;,c0#t1;,I%20just%20know%20that;,c0;.t1;,I%20just%20knew%20that;,c1)

Comment: If you still know it, *I just know that ...* is the better choice. You can find a lot of "I just knew that ..." in books because most narration is in past tenses.

Comment: So you are saying that, normally, if I *knew* something, I forgot it in some time later, and I don't remember it now.

Comment: @Santi: If you're referring to something you knew at some past time, but have forgotten and thus *no longer know*, you'd be much more likely to introduce an auxiliary verb so you can emphasise the fact of it being past tense - *"I **did** know that, but I've forgotten"*. If you use the simpler form *"I **knew** that"* it tends to imply *"I **already** knew that"* (and ***still do***), since we don't normally think of *knowing things* as a temporary state of affairs.

Comment: @SantiSantichaivekin: If you want to refer to a poitn in time in the past at which you became sure of whatever it is you're referring to, then you would say "I just knew that..."  For example "When I saw the postman coming with a package, I just knew that my order had arrived."  Compare "I am certain" and "I was certain".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the intention is to convey that I *now* know something that I didn't know until about two minutes ago, neither of OP's suggestions are appropriate.

> 1: I can't say exactly what's wrong with Jack - I **just know** that I don't like him.
>   2: Jill says Jack is a convicted child molester - I **just knew** there was something wrong with him.
>    3: I **just found out** (or **discovered, became aware**, etc.) that Jack is a paedophile

In #1 and #2, ***just*** is really an "emphasising modifier" for ***know*** (akin to ***only, simply, merely,***, etc.).
In #3, ***just*** is a "temporal qualifier", effectively meaning ***very recently, not long ago***.

---

In this particular context there's nothing to be gained by comparing NGrams for present and past tense, they simply reflect the fact that the usage illustrated in #1 and #2 above can occur in respect of things believed/known both *currently* and *previously*.

Comment: So you suggest me to use #3 instead. Yep! that sounds beter^ ^~.PS. And is "neither of them" used as a plural?

Comment: @Santi: If you want to learn how *write* pedantically, you'll probably find plenty of like-minded people willing to assert that it should always be ***neither is***. But If you want to learn to *speak* like a native, [ignore any supposed "rules" about this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/10308/2637). Bear in mind that resources like NGrams overstate excessively formal *written* usages at the expense of casual *spoken* usages which occur far more often but aren't easily accesible for statistical analysis.

Comment: ...also note that it's *"I suggest you use #3"*, not *"I suggest you **to** use #3"*. So from your perspective, it's *"So you suggest [that] **I** use #3 instead"*.